# What are the differences between process data segment and resident set size?

Tags: memory, ulimit

I searched how to limit memory usage for a single process and found 3 results,`ulimit -d`, `-m` and `-v`, which stand for data seg size(process's data segment), max memory size(resident set size) and virtual memory. I am confused about what these "memory"  mean.